# Why doesn't Reflect object have `defineMetadata` and `getOwnMetadata` methods

Tags: javascript, reflect-metadata

I'm looking at this [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) shim, it shows methods available on `Reflect` object like `Reflect.defineMetadata` and `Reflect.getOwnMetadata`. The [MDN page on Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) object doesn't list these methods. Are those two different `Reflect` objects?

Comment: reflect-metadata seems to be targetting es-next where the reflect object is in es2015.

Comment: @DanielA.White, thanks, so do you think that's different Reflect object, or the same object but enhanced?

Comment: Maybe. You should ask that library

Comment: @DanielA.White, got it, I'll ask and put an answer here)

Answer (score 1):

The `reflect-metadata` package is extending that namespace so by default that method is not available in the original `Reflect` Prototype but this package is extending those functions in the same API to leverage the benefit of storing metadata.